# generating random number with RNGCRYPTOSERVICEPROVIDER within specified range

Tags: .net, vb.net, random, cryptography

I have come with the following coding to generate range within 1000-9999:

```
Dim byt As Byte() = New Byte(1000) {}

Dim rngCrypto As New RNGCryptoServiceProvider()
rngCrypto.GetBytes(byt)

Dim randomNumber As Integer = BitConverter.ToInt32(byt, 9999)
Label4.Text = randomNumber
```

It shows the error:

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: `startIndex`

i have done following code. is it correct?

Public Sub secrand()

```
    Static r As Random = Nothing

    If r Is Nothing Then
        Dim seed() As Byte = New Byte(4) {}
        Dim rng As New RNGCryptoServiceProvider
        rng.GetBytes(seed)
        r = New Random(BitConverter.ToInt32(seed, 0))
        Label4.Text = r.Next(1000, 9999)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: now i have did like this: Static r As Random = Nothing

        If r Is Nothing Then
            Dim seed() As Byte = New Byte(4) {}
            Dim rng As New RNGCryptoServiceProvider
            rng.GetBytes(seed)
            r = New Random(BitConverter.ToInt32(seed, 0))
            Label4.Text = r.Next(1000, 9999) is it correct way????

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second parameter to `BitConverter.ToInt32` is an offset into the byte array. It should be 0 for you. There is also no reason to get 1000 byttes if you're using only 4 of them.

A working version in C#:

```
public static int RandomUniform(int count)
{
    if(count <= 0)
         throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("count");
    var rng=new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
    var bytes=new byte[8];
    rng.GetBytes(bytes, 0);
    return BitConverter.ToUInt64() % (uint)count;
}

Label4.Text = 1000 + RandomUniform(9000);
```

In VB.net this will look similar to

```
Public Shared Function RandomUniform(count As Integer) As Integer
    If count <= 0 Then
        Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException("count")
    End If
    Dim rng = New RNGCryptoServiceProvider()
    Dim bytes = New Byte(8) {}
    rng.GetBytes(bytes, 0)
    Return BitConverter.ToUInt64() Mod CUInt(count)
End Function
```

This code has two weaknesses:

1. It's quite slow. The per-call overhead of `RNGCryptoServiceProvider.GetBytes` is large.
   For better performance use a buffer of several kilobytes and only call `GetBytes` when it's used up.
2. It's not perfectly uniform, but the bias should be small enough for most applications.

   Even when using a value for `count` that exhibits maximal bias you will need over ten billion samples to detect it, whereas for `System.Random` a handful are enough. i.e the bias is about 8 billion times smaller than for `System.Random`.

If either weakness is unacceptable for you, you can look into my [random number generator project](https://github.com/MerkatorProject/Merkator.Tools/tree/master/Merkator.Tools/Random) which offers fast, secure and unbiased numbers. But this comes at the cost of adding an external library instead of simply writing a few lines of code.

Comment: Just in case, for those not familiar with c#, `%` would be the `mod` operator in [vb.net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se0w9esz(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I have done this: is it correct??? dim rng as new rngcryptoserviceprovider  
Dim seed() As Byte = New Byte(4) {}
            rng.GetBytes(seed)
            r = New Random(BitConverter.ToInt32(seed, 0))
            Label4.Text = r.Next(1000, 9999)

Comment: "Not perfectly uniform but it shouldn't matter" - if it doesn't matter you may as well just use Random.

Comment: @Rawling The bias is *much* smaller than with `System.Random.` The distribution of a `UInt64` modulo a number smaller than two billion is *very good*, but not perfect. For crypto purposes you mainly need unpredictability and not perfect randomness.

Comment: @user1849470 Why are you using `System.Random`? Use the VB.net equivalent of my code, and not what you're using.

Comment: @CodesInChaos I'd hoped `Random` might be uniform over a (comparitively) small range, but if it's not... fair enough.

Comment: @CodesInChaos whts the problem with random? i m not getting ur code so tht i can't put it in my scope...

Comment: @Rawling Expanded the answer a bit to talk about the size of the bias. For a reference of my `System.Random` is bad, see my rant at [Why use the C# class System.Random at all](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6842191/445517)

Comment: @user1849470 It's not designed to be secure. Your specific use is probably OK, but I wouldn't rely on it. I've added a VB version of my code.

Comment: @CodesInChaos it is showing error like this : Argument not specified for parameter 'startIndex' of 'Public Shared Function ToUInt64(value() As Byte, startIndex As Integer) As ULong

Comment: @CodesInChaos i have done this to overcome the error: Return BitConverter.ToUInt64(bytes, 0) Mod CUInt(count). Now it is working well. is it now a correct way of implementation of RNGCRYPTOSERVICEPROVIDER ???

Comment: @CodesInChaos i have few queries for you. 1. what is signification of MOD operation? 2. why we are adding 1000  in generation, can't we add any number and what is its significanc?? 3. Is it satisfy the use of RNGcryptoserviceprovider??

Comment: 1) It maps the large number returned by `BitConverter` to the range `0` to `9000 - 1`. Since you want the range `1000` to `9999` you need to add 1000.

Comment: @CodesInChaos i have done some manipulation on ur code i.e Return BitConverter.ToUInt64 **(bytes, 0)** Mod CUInt(count). is it correct??

Comment: Post your new code, and I'll take a look. Adding the `0` param to `ToUInt64` is correct.

Comment: @CodesInChaos i just manipulated one line else the whole code is same. will the MOD operation really provide uniforms to our function? i dn't know how to test it hence

Comment: @CodesInChaos if i want to accomplished same thing for list of button from 0-9 then ???

Comment: then you use `RandomUniform(10)`