# Can Random.NextDouble method ever return '1.0'?

Tags: c#, random, numbers

in the [Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.nextdouble.aspx) `Random.NextDouble` it is written that

**Returns a random number between 0.0 and 1.0.**

I want to ask that is it possible that it will return `1` in any case?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the upvotes.  Did you read the next sentence of the documentation in that link?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No - according to the doc, zero is inclusive, but 1 is not:

> A double-precision floating point number greater than or equal to 0.0, and less than 1.0.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.nextdouble.aspx)

Comment: I can't help wondering if it can return a value between `1E-323` and `1E-17`. One could think it somehow generated a random "mantissa" with a fixed "scale".

Comment: Another thing: A number strictly less than `1.0` might display as `1` with the usual string representation. For example `double d = 0.99999999999999978; Console.WriteLine(d < 1.0); /* "True" */ Console.WriteLine(d); /* "1" */`

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen That can happen in theory, but won't happen with the current implementation of `Random.NextDouble`, since it only uses about 31 or 32 bits instead of the full 53. Doesn't use subnorms either. It's simply something like `randomInt(0..2^31-1)/2^31`

Comment: @CodesInChaos Interesting. I was thinking about something like this. I experimented a bit, and it looks like `myRandom.NextDouble() * (Math.Pow(2.0, 31.0) - 1.0)` always gives an integer. However, it is was not easy to detect from `BitConverter.GetBytes(myRandom.NextDouble())` because the factor seems to be not a power of two, but one less than a power of two, [2147483647](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2147483647).

Comment: @CodesInChaos Are you looking at the implementation? I think it's strange that the denominator is odd, 2147483647. Is the maximal output of `NextDouble()` then equal to `2147483646.0 / 2147483647.0`, or is the answer we're commenting on incomplete (I mean maybe `1.0 == 2147483647.0 / 2147483647.0` **is** possible)?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen I don't remember the details, but there was some weirdness in that area. I think `Random.Next()` never returns `int.MaxValue`, but returns `int.MaxValue-1` more often, or something like that. `Random.NextDouble`'s issues also bleed over to `Random.Next(n)` causing significant bias for some `n`.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Since 6 divides neither 2147483647 nor 2147483648, one could imagine that they implemented `.Next(6)` in a way that distributes the 2147483647 outcomes unevenly among 0, 1, 2, ..., 5. They probably just use integer division by 6. If that's their way, consider `.Next(2000000000)`. The lowest values, 0 to 147483646, would have _double_ probability compared to the remaining values, 147483647 to 1999999999. If that's the case, maybe the empirical mean value of a lot of `.Next(2000000000)` numbers will deviate from the expected result?

Comment: @Jeppe They must have implemented `Next(n)` as something like `NextDouble()*n`. That causes a huge bias for some `n`, such as [`1431655765`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6842191/445517).

Comment: I wanted to add a note because I had to hunt a bug which was related to this. NextDouble may not return 1, but casting the result to float CAN return 1.