# Uniform random numbers to simulate with ten decimal places

Tags: c#, random, uniform

I'm tring to run an specific simulation, i have some code implemented but the result is not the one i'm expecting, i need to generate random uniform(ranged from 0 to 1) numbers with 10 decimal places (in order to convert that in other distribution). Example: 0,0345637897, 0,3445627876, 0,9776428487

this is the code:

```
double next = r.Next(1000000000, 9999999999);
return double.Parse(String.Format("0.{0}", next));
```

Comment: Please post your existing code so we can see what you already tried

Comment: What are your results? (Aside from unexpected). What's wrong with them?

Comment: Pretty unclear, could we have some code too please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be enough:

```
double v = Math.Round(myRandom.NextDouble(), 10);
```

The difference between `0.123`  and `0.1230000000` is a matter of formatting, see the answer from @SamIAm.

---

After the Edit:

```
double next = r.Next(1000000000, 9999999999);
return double.Parse(String.Format("0.{0}", next));
```

this is getting an **integer** between 1000000000 and 9999999999 and then uses the default culture to convert it to a double (in the 0 ... 1.0 range).

Since you seem to use the comma (`,`) as a decimal separator, at least use

```
return double.Parse(String.Format("0.{0}", next), CultureInfo.Invariant);
```

Comment: If you dont care so much about the random quality, then yes

Comment: Again, what is 'quality' in this context?

Comment: Just read the post in the link I posted. It explains it

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to pad your output? because you can do that with `String.Format()`

```
string s = String.Format({0:0000000000}, i);
```

you can also do it with a double or float

```
string s = String.Format("{0:0.0000000000}", d);
```

---

if you need a random double, just make one, and pad it with 10 decimal places when you print.

```
Random random = new Random();
double d = random.NextDouble()
```

Comment: I really don't think that's what the question is asking.

Comment: That `random.NextDouble() * 9999999999` is totally wrong, the LongRandom is not what is being asked.

Comment: @HenkHolterman sorry, It was the comma used as a decimal point that got me confused

Answer (score -1):

I suggest using RNGCryptoServiceProvider. It will produces high-quality random numbers

See this post: [Why use the C# class System.Random at all instead of System.Security.Cryptography.RandomNumberGenerator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257299/why-use-the-c-sharp-class-system-random-at-all-instead-of-system-security-crypto/6842191#6842191)

Comment: Could you explain how exactly would you use that?

Comment: What determines the 'quality' of a random number?

Comment: @HenkHolterman How random the number is. Random() uses the computers clock or whatever, creating repeating sequences. Wich is bad! True random needs something like reading static space disturbence or something...

Comment: I know the difference, see my answer to the linked question. The OP only wants to simulate something. Statistical arguments apply, security does not.