# Alternative to System.Web.Security.Membership.GeneratePassword in aspnetcore (netcoreapp1.0)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0, .net-standard-1.5

Is there any alternative to `System.Web.Security.Membership.GeneratePassword` in `AspNetCore` (`netcoreapp1.0`).

The easiest way would be to just use a `Guid.NewGuid().ToString("n")` which is long enough to be worthy of a password but it's not fully random.

Comment: What does `System.Web.Security.Membership.GeneratePassword` do that you don't want?

Comment: All that method does is [generate a random password](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.generatepassword(v=vs.110).aspx), that super easy to do yourself.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Here's a class/method, based on the source of [`Membership.GeneratePassword`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/Security/Membership.cs,fe744ec40cace139,references) of  that works on .NET Core:

```
public static class Password
{
    private static readonly char[] Punctuations = "!@#$%^&*()_-+=[{]};:>|./?".ToCharArray();

    public static string Generate(int length, int numberOfNonAlphanumericCharacters)
    {
        if (length < 1 || length > 128)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(nameof(length));
        }

        if (numberOfNonAlphanumericCharacters > length || numberOfNonAlphanumericCharacters < 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(nameof(numberOfNonAlphanumericCharacters));
        }

        using (var rng = RandomNumberGenerator.Create())
        {
            var byteBuffer = new byte[length];

            rng.GetBytes(byteBuffer);

            var count = 0;
            var characterBuffer = new char[length];

            for (var iter = 0; iter < length; iter++)
            {
                var i = byteBuffer[iter] % 87;

                if (i < 10)
                {
                    characterBuffer[iter] = (char)('0' + i);
                }
                else if (i < 36)
                {
                    characterBuffer[iter] = (char)('A' + i - 10);
                }
                else if (i < 62)
                {
                    characterBuffer[iter] = (char)('a' + i - 36);
                }
                else
                {
                    characterBuffer[iter] = Punctuations[i - 62];
                    count++;
                }
            }

            if (count >= numberOfNonAlphanumericCharacters)
            {
                return new string(characterBuffer);
            }

            int j;
            var rand = new Random();

            for (j = 0; j < numberOfNonAlphanumericCharacters - count; j++)
            {
                int k;
                do
                {
                    k = rand.Next(0, length);
                }
                while (!char.IsLetterOrDigit(characterBuffer[k]));

                characterBuffer[k] = Punctuations[rand.Next(0, Punctuations.Length)];
            }

            return new string(characterBuffer);
        }
    }
}
```

I've omitted the `do...while` loop over the [`CrossSiteScriptingValidation.IsDangerousString`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/CrossSiteScriptingValidation.cs,3c599cea73c5293b). You can add that back in yourself if you need it.

You use it like this:

```
var password = Password.Generate(32, 12);
```

Also, make sure you reference `System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms`.

Comment: This was very helpful. Is there some neat way to add the rest of nonalphanumeric characters, [cause you omitted some ;)]? Creating StringRaw class or something?

Comment: This method (as the one in the framework) has a bias due to the use of the modulo in `byte % 87`. Might not be a problem for most use cases, but something to keep in mind. Bias changes if characters are added to or removed from the `Punctuations` array.

Comment: This will throw, with the punctuation list in this length, if `i == 86` as you will get an out of index error.

Comment: @Razze Hah, Microsoft probably never got the bug report because (I'm assuming) very few people generate passwords longer than 85 characters :P

Comment: `i` is not connected to the password length, but to the length of your special signs.

We ended up doing something like `var i = byteBuffer[iter] % Punctuations.length + 62;`

Comment: I'm wondering if Rene's answer below should be merged into khellangs answer?

Answer (score 3):

System.Random doesn't provide enough entropy when used for security reasons.

https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/331.html

[Why use the C# class System.Random at all instead of System.Security.Cryptography.RandomNumberGenerator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257299/why-use-the-c-sharp-class-system-random-at-all-instead-of-system-security-crypto)

Please see the example below for a more secure version of @khellang version

```
    public static class Password
    {
        private static readonly char[] Punctuations = "!@#$%^&*()_-+[{]}:>|/?".ToCharArray();
        public static string Generate(int length, int numberOfNonAlphanumericCharacters)
        {
            if (length < 1 || length > 128)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("length");
            }

            if (numberOfNonAlphanumericCharacters > length || numberOfNonAlphanumericCharacters < 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("numberOfNonAlphanumericCharacters");
            }

            using (var rng = RandomNumberGenerator.Create())
            {
                var byteBuffer = new byte[length];
               
                rng.GetBytes(byteBuffer);

                var count = 0;
                var characterBuffer = new char[length];

                for (var iter = 0; iter < length; iter++)
                {
                    var i = byteBuffer[iter] % 87;

                    if (i < 10)
                    {
                        characterBuffer[iter] = (char)('0' + i);
                    }
                    else if (i < 36)
                    {
                        characterBuffer[iter] = (char)('A' + i - 10);
                    }
                    else if (i < 62)
                    {
                        characterBuffer[iter] = (char)('a' + i - 36);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        characterBuffer[iter] = Punctuations[GetRandomInt(rng, Punctuations.Length)];
                        count++;
                    }
                }

                if (count >= numberOfNonAlphanumericCharacters)
                {
                    return new string(characterBuffer);
                }

                int j;
                
                for (j = 0; j < numberOfNonAlphanumericCharacters - count; j++)
                {
                    int k;
                    do
                    {
                        k = GetRandomInt(rng, length);
                    }
                    while (!char.IsLetterOrDigit(characterBuffer[k]));

                    characterBuffer[k] = Punctuations[GetRandomInt(rng, Punctuations.Length)];
                }

                return new string(characterBuffer);
            }
        }

        private static int GetRandomInt(RandomNumberGenerator randomGenerator)
        {
            var buffer = new byte[4];
            randomGenerator.GetBytes(buffer);

            return BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer);
        }
        private static int GetRandomInt(RandomNumberGenerator randomGenerator, int maxInput)
        {
            return Math.Abs(GetRandomInt(randomGenerator) % maxInput);
        }
    }
```